# Setting default apps for skype

Tags: google-maps, skype

Is there a way to change the default apps to use with Skype? I am very annoyed at how stupid Bing is when handling addresses compared to Google maps and would like to use Google maps as my default. How can I make this happen?

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? Please don't do that, read and take note of [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers). If you have new information you should edit it into the original question instead of asking a new one.

Comment: My bad. I was not sure which department would be best for handling this question. After I submitted it, I found what looked like a similar question in a different community and asked the question there. Some helpful soul migrated the question, so that both copies showed up in the same place. I understand that this is not pukka. My apologies. Lesson learned. It will not happen again.